# Get data by filtering and grouping LINQ query

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

Could someone help me to write a code to get data from grouped and filtered query?

Data are from simple datatable, and what I need is how to solve a problem if user enter only one of search param, but also have a possibility to enter more param?

```
public class Journal
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

/*variables entered bu user:
searchParam1
searchParam2
...
searchParamN
*/

using (var dbContext = new databaseContext())
{
    var serchresult = dbContext.Journals
        .Where(p => p.Field1.StartsWith(SearchParam1) && 
                    p.Field2.StartsWith(SearchPParam2))
        .GroupBy(f => f.ID)
        .ToList();
}
```

To get filtered data I'v tried:

```
result = from tr in dbContext.Journals select tr;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam1)) {
    result = result.Where(tr => tr.Field1.StartsWith(SearchParam1));
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam2)) {
    result = result.Where(tr => tr.Field2.StartsWith(SearchParam2));
}
```

But I need to add grouping :(

Comment: If I filtering not grouped query I write simple like this:

Comment: update your query with error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Split your query in two parts. In the first part do the dynamic filtering and in the second part do the rest.

```
var source = dbContext.Journals.AsQueryble();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam1))
    source = source.Where(tr => tr.Field1.StartsWith(SearchParam1));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam2))
    source = source.Where(tr => tr.Field2.StartsWith(SearchParam2));
var serchresult = source
      .GroupBy(f => f.ID)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: I need to convert serchresult to List witch I could show in form.. could Is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible as soon as it's clear what exactly do you want to achieve. I would suggest you posting another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify like this.

```
result = dbContext.Journals.ToList();
result.Where(tr => ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam1) && tr.Field1.StartsWith(SearchParam1)) 
                 || ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam2) && tr.Field2.StartsWith(SearchParam2)))
      .GroupBy(f => f.ID)
      .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x=> new { ID = g.Key.ID, x.Field1, x.Field2 })) 
      .ToList();
```

Comment: You can, but the generated SQL query will be inefficient. Simply does not always mean better.

Comment: Agreed, just want to let OP know that we could combine both the statements, and do this.

Comment: Btw, I think you should recheck the conditions. It should be `((String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam1) || tr.Field1.StartsWith(SearchParam1)) && ...)`

Comment: Sounds correct to me, if the string is not empty then check use for filtering. Am I overlook something?

Comment: Usually (and in OP case) null or empty means skip the filter, while your condition evaluates to `false` in that case instead of `true`. De Morgan's law, you know :)

Comment: @Songaila you just need to use `.GroupBy(f => new {f.ID, f.OtherField })`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new in c# You helped so much

Comment: public List<dataEntity1> GroupedList

Comment: I need GroupedList with values by ID from grouped query: public List<dataEntity1> GroupedList;  var searchResult = query
                      .GroupBy(f =>  f.ID)
                      .Select(g => new { ID = g.Key.ID, g.Key.Field1, g.Key.Field2 })

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Seems there is some missing bracket, just cross verify your code.